# function declared as void* foo()

Tags: c, void, void-pointers

I've come across this piece of code in my O.S book:

```
void *foo()
{
     // does something

     pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

What is the meaning of `void *foo`? 
Does that mean the function return a pointer to something of type `void`?

Comment: It means that `foo` is a function that can take any number of arguments and returns a pointer to an object of any type (or, more pedantically speaking, a pointer to an object of type `void`, but there are no objects of type `void`).

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void *` means it returns a pointer to some type, it isn't specified which. In order to be used the pointer is casted to the appropriate type and then used. The fact that `void *foo` is just a matter of spacing.

Check out this [explanation](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/programming/node87.html)

Answer (score 4):

No, it means that the function returns an pointer of the *untyped* type - `void*`.

This is a "generic" pointer type. Any pointer to data can be cast to `void*`, and returned back to the caller. However, in order to *dereference* the pointer, you must cast it to a non-void pointer type (`int*`, `long*`, `char*`, and so on).

Comment: I would say the pointer is typed, but it's the type it points to that is untyped.